# How do I differentiate between a tab and a space in a string in python

Tags: python, string, whitespace, delimiter, csv

I'm trying to write a function that finds the most common delimiter of a string, it's either a comma, a space or a tab. My issue is that the function doesn't read tabs and instead reads them as a bunch of spaces. Here's the code I have:

```
def which_delimiter(input_str):

    # count total number of spaces, commas and tabs in the string
    spaces = input_str.count(" ")
    commas = input_str.count(",")
    tabs = input_str.count("\t")

    # return the delimiter with the highest frequency
    # if there is none, raise an error
    if spaces == 0 and commas == 0 and tabs == 0:
        raise AssertionError
    elif spaces > commas and spaces > tabs:
        return "spaces"
    elif commas > spaces and commas > tabs:
        return "commas"
    else:
        return "tabs"
```

Comment: Are you sure input_str actually contains tabs and not just spaces?

Comment: Your function looks correct to me. Can it be that wherever `input_str` comes from replaces tabs by 8 spaces?
 What happens on your machine if you run `input_str("foo\tbar")`?

Comment: instead of raising `AssertionError` we can use `assert` statement on a condition

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your `input_str` contains `\t` char, then your function is correct.

But if you char contains a tab, it will be interpreted as 4 spaces characters. 
A workaround for you is to count the bunch of spaces using `input_str.count("    ")`

Which gives :

```py
def which_delimiter(input_str):

    # count total number of spaces, commas and tabs in the string
    spaces = input_str.count(" ")
    commas = input_str.count(",")
    tabs = input_str.count("\t")
    bunch_spaces = input_str.count("    ")

    # You can count tabs and bunch spaces separately or regroup them, using for example
    # tabs_total_count = tabs + bunch_spaces.
    # Then you use your if/elif statements as you want with above elements.
```